# Update all the records of a field in a table whose value is only in another table

Tags: mysql, record

I have table A:

```
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| name          | id_product | price | price_medium|
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| phone         |         1  |   300 |         300 |
| mouse         |         2  |    50 |          75 |
| phone         |         1  |   250 |         300 |
| keyboard      |         3  |   100 |         100 |
| mouse         |         2  |   100 |          75 |
| phone         |         1  |   350 |         300 |
+---------------+------------+------+--------------+
```

In table B is a temporary table, products are added each time a purchase is made and then deleted.
When it is sent, I want to update in table A the column "price_medium" that I have in table B whose product_id is the addition.

```
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| name          | id_product | price | price_medium|
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| phone         |         1  |   100 |         220 |
| mouse         |         2  |   125 |          92 |
| phone         |         1  |   100 |         220 |
+---------------+------------+------+--------------+
```

The final result would be in table A

```
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| name          | id_product | price | price_medium|
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| phone         |         1  |   300 |         220 |
| mouse         |         2  |    50 |          92 |
| phone         |         1  |   250 |         220 |
| keyboard      |         3  |   100 |         100 |
| mouse         |         2  |   100 |          92 |
| phone         |         1  |   350 |         220 |
+---------------+------------+------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can do an `Inner Join` between the two tables using `id_product`
- Use `Set` to update `price_medium` in tableA (equal to `price_medium` in tableB)

Try:

```
UPDATE tableA AS tA
JOIN tableB AS tB ON tB.id_product = tA.id_product 
SET tA.price_medium = tB.price_medium
```

Comment: Thank you very much Madhur Bhaiya, he has returned to help me again, I appreciate it, it works perfectly, I aim it, when I have 15 reputation points I will give him points.